# Where does Wordpress Mu DB store the link of network admin dashboard

Tags: multisite

I have change xx_site table domain but 
https://example.com/wp-admin/network/
still points to old domain.

So where does it store this url ?

Comment: Do a searcha nd replace in your DB, also, add these changes to your wp-config.php 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php

Comment: @sven hi thanks it wasn't in db but in wp-config

Comment: So it works now?